# New to Excel and linking to a wav file on my local hard drive

Tags: excel, hyperlink, wav

I've digitized a collection of gig tapes for someone and thought I would create an excel file/book with basic info (Performance date, venue, and so on) and a link to the digitized .wav file. The purpose is for researching the tapes and not for listening to the music.

I'm on Mac using Excel 2019(offline). I have Quicktime set as my default audio player. All files are on my hard drive and not on the web.

I thought it would be easy but after creating test links I just got warnings that the link was unsafe and a second error window saying "can't open the file".

Am I correct that Excel does not link easily to audio files and open them in the default media player? I see a lot of talk about coding to make it work.